# Django csrf token error only with uploading file using django-pwa

Tags: python, django

When update user profile model using model form in django:

**Raise `csrf token missing or incorrect` only with uploading file.**

**In case of without file attached, I can update other fields.**

It is occurred while using `django-pwa` and `serviceworker.js`.

https://github.com/silviolleite/django-pwa

model.py file:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='avatars', blank=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=128)
    last_name = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=128)
    birthday = models.DateField(blank=True, default='1990-12-01')
    town = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=128)
```

forms.py file:

```
class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('avatar', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'birthday', 'town')
```

in views.py file:

```
@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class ProfileView(FormView):
    form_class = UserProfileForm
    template_name = 'profiles/profile.html'

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.username = kwargs.get('username')
        self.user = get_user_model().objects.get(username=self.username)
        self.userprofile = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=self.user)[0]
        self.form = UserProfileForm({'first_name': self.userprofile.first_name,
                                     'last_name': self.userprofile.last_name,
                                     'avatar': self.userprofile.avatar,
                                     'birthday': self.userprofile.birthday,
                                     'town': self.userprofile.town)
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        return {'userprofile': self.userprofile, 'selecteduser': self.user, 'form': self.form}

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_form(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.form_class(self.request.POST, self.request.FILES, instance=self.userprofile)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save(commit=True)
        return redirect('profiles:profile', self.user.username)
```

in profile.html file:

```
<form method="post" action="." enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.non_field_errors }}
    {% for field in form %}
        <div class="form-group">
            {{ field }}
            {{ field.errors }}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Update" />
</form>
```

and software viersions:

```
ubuntu 18.04
nginx 1.14.0
uwsgi 2.0.18
Django 2.2
Django-CMS 3.7
django-pwa 1.0.5
```

In addition, also in case of uploading file on django-cms is raised error:

raise `AttributeError: 'TemporaryFileUploadHandler' object has no attribute 'file'`, and request content-length is zero.

I have never seen such problem.

What should I check? Please tell me how to resolve.

Comment: Can  you check if your FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE in your settings is set high enough? I know it does not sound logical to be connected to your problem but I had a similar issue and that resolved it.

Comment: Thanks. My FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE is default(2.5 MB) and upload file size is 35KB. I was checked request.body content, so `request.FILES` was empty and `request.META['CONTENT_LENGTH'] = 0`. And it is occurred when using `django-pwa` and `serviceworker.js`. I will write the additional information in question.